# How can I modify the point of view of this photo?

Tags: image-editing, perspective

How can I modify this picture to make it seem like the pizza is shown from above?
[image: Side view of a pizza]

Comment: There's not enough information from an image like this to do this very properly. I recommend getting new images from the top down or finding some that are free to use online

Comment: Not enough information: it's true. You'll note that there is bread only at the bottom edge of the picture. There's no bread visible at the top edge of the picture. But for a real pizza, there will be a small ring of bread only all around the pizza. That's what you won't get back. Similar for the wooden platter.

Comment: If you must have *this exact pizza* from a different angle, the only way to do it convincingly is with **projection mapping** and **projection painting**. Make an approximated 3D model of your pizza and then project the 2D photo onto that mesh. Then, because some parts of the geometry were not visible to the camera in the original photo, those will need to be painted back in by cloning parts of the existing image. I'm not sure if you care about this pizza enough to start learning Blender, but I'm just letting you know [it is possible](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gz4qV5_zuMo).

Answer (score 19):

You can't change the actual viewing angle of a 2D photograph in Photoshop. It's not possible.

You could only distort the image by stretching it, but it wouldn't be a true top view.  At a push, you could try to remove the distortion using the Liquify filter, but ultimately it would be better to take photos of the pizza from different angles.

An example: Image stretched vertically (left). Removed distortion using the Liquify filter (right)

[image]

What I did here was use the Liquify filter's Forward Warp tool, to move the centre of the cuts into the middle, and using the same tool set to a smaller size, I also thinned the crust and board by moving them a little at a time.   There's still a little stretchy distortion around the top edge, which could also be removed similarly if you have more time.

Comment: The result is nice, but you will get into trouble with pizzas with more "3-dimensional" toppings. If something is sticking up it will become more obvious that the perspective is distorted.

Comment: @Wollf yes absolutely!!

Comment: That really is a better result that I would have expected. Kudos to Billy Kerr

Answer (score 1):

Perspective warp only - you can play with it a bit. Just another opinion.
BTW - 10 slices? Must be a hungry crew! :)

[image]

Comment: I could never eat 10 slices.  Better just cut it into 8 pieces.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to recreate details that would be revealed if the photo was taken from a different angle (and hide some others). There are already some AI applications that can guess those missing details, but probably not yet for 3D transformations applications...

However, if you'd like to do that manually anyway, here's a very rough plan:

1. Correct the perspective of the main object.
2. Add non-existing details by reusing those already existing, that look similar, making sure that the lighting is correct.
3. Remove any unwanted details or squash those that would take much less space in the new view.
4. Correct any perspective-related issues at the detail level.